# Gradle multiple subproject with different spring boot plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have multi project build structure and spring boot is applied from the parent to all subprojects. Here's the parent **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
            url 'http://someurl.com/repository/MavenRepositoryGroup/'
        }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE"
  }
}


subprojects  {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
..
..
..
}
}
```

Among multiple subprojects, I have a requirement to upgrade just **one** subproject to spring boot 2 version. How to do it?

Comment: can you post where do you manage you version, I mean ext{}

Comment: maybe you can find some answer or ideas from this gradle forum question : https://discuss.gradle.org/t/multiple-versions-of-custom-plugin-in-buildscript-dependencies-of-multi-project-build/24864

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy, just declare plugins in subprojects directly, where they are used. BTW, consider using [new `plugins` DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) instead of `apply`. Take a look at a [demo project](https://gitlab.com/madhead-playgrounds/so53381565) I created for you. Here are the most interesting parts:

*settings.gradle*:

```
rootProject.name = "so53381565"

enableFeaturePreview("IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT")

include(":a")
include(":b")
include(":c")
```

*build.gradle*:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "4.10.2"
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}
```

*a/build.gradle*:

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "1.5.8.RELEASE"
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter"
}
```

*b/build.gradle*:

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "1.5.17.RELEASE"
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter"
}
```

*c/build.gradle*:

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.0.6.RELEASE"
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.6.RELEASE"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter"
}
```

*App.java*:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(SpringVersion.getVersion());
    }
}
```

`App.java` is the same in all three subprojects. Executing `./gradlew clean :a:bootRun :b:bootRun :c:bootRun` will output something like:

```
…
4.3.12.RELEASE
…
4.3.20.RELEASE
…
5.0.10.RELEASE
…
```

As you see, you're using three different Springs in three different subprojects.

---

**EDIT**

First of all, you can still use `apply`, just put them in subprojects.

Second, you can use `plugins` with your own repositories and dependencies, even with those not published in Gradle's Plugin Repository [by adding](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management) a `pluginManagement` block in `settings.gradle` (this is Kotlin DSL from my project):

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        add(jcenter())
        add(maven("http://my.jfrog.io"))

    }

    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "by.dev.madhead.some-plugin") {
                useModule("by.dev.madhead:some-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am able to use `by.dev.madhead.some-plugin` in `plugins` DSL across the project:

```
plugins {
    id("by.dev.madhead.some-plugin").version("42")
}
```

And it will be substituted by `by.dev.madhead:some-gradle-plugin:42`

Comment: This is great but the reason I included is old style plugin is I have to define my own nexus servers not the public one if you noticed. Is there a way to define such proxy servers in new plugin DSL?

Comment: How can one set one plugin version in the central `build.gradle` and still override that version in a subproject?

Comment: @dinvlad, please, don't ask questions in comments. Start a new question instead.